Why printf("Hello World") example so hard in STM32Cubeide
well I am using Nucleo Board which is F401RE. Its UART2 has already connected Stlink. Since it is connected to UART2, the print code should have easily worked over USB with the computer, but things don’t work that way in the ST world. or I am dont know.
for printing I have to add this code otherwise not printing
/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

int __io_putchar(int ch)
{
 uint8_t c[1];
 c[0] = ch & 0x00FF;
 HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, &*c, 1, 10);
 return ch;
}

int _write(int file,char *ptr, int len)
{
 int DataIdx;
 for(DataIdx= 0; DataIdx< len; DataIdx++)
 {
 __io_putchar(*ptr++);
 }
return len;
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

my test code
int main(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */

    /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART2_UART_Init();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1) {
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
        printf("Merhaba Fixaj STM32!\r\n");
        HAL_Delay(1000);
    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

So the code working:
uart2 settings
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
    huart2.Instance = USART2;
    huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
    huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
    huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
    huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
    huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
    huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
    huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
    if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

Is there a simpler way to run the printf code?

Aside: &*c would normally just be written as c.

If you consider this is "hard", you probably spoiled by Arduino where it try to hide every implementation details from you. When programming without the Arduino framework, you will need to do a lot of more work yourself. In this case, it needs  to re-route the io that was writing data to 'stdout' to the UART by writing your own implementation of _write() function.

In the C library, printf is implemented in terms of write.  write in a desktop system such as linux is a system call, so the code in your first block of code would be implemented in the operating system kernel.
Since in a bare metal system such as this you do not have file IO provided by the system, you have to implement these ten lines of code yourself.  This is really not any great hardship.
It wouldn't make sense for this to be hard coded in the library because every platform uses different drivers and every board uses different different UART instances.

well there is a different approch but same as it need some code to printf()
Mastering STM32 book 
with adding retarget files (.c and .h source and header files) your code.
for preventing function conflict you should convert this code to comments in syscalls.c
/*
int _close(int file)
{
  (void)file;
  return -1;
}

int _fstat(int file, struct stat *st)
{
  (void)file;
  st->st_mode = S_IFCHR;
  return 0;
}

int _isatty(int file)
{
  (void)file;
  return 1;
}
*/

no further setting needs,

Well, it is still the same, it just that someone write the entire retarget.c for you which included the custom _write() implementation.

This code snippet is not relevant to the question, and linking to offsite answers is not allowed.
